# User selection menu from a PowerShell array with more than 9 items

Tags: arrays, powershell, menu

I have a PowerShell function that I use to generate interactive menus on the fly. I pass values to an array name $mlist and then generate the menu based on the contents of the array. The user simply selects the number associated with their desired choice. The code works fine when the array contains 9 items or less. If the array contains more than 9 items, the only selection I can choose is "1". Choosing any other selection results in the menu being displayed again. I have it encapsulated in a while statement and this is the desired function when no item is selected. So basically it ignores any entry other than "1" when the array contains more than 9 items. Here is the code:

```
$global:ans = $null
$global:selection = $null
While ($ans -lt 1 -or $ans -gt $mlist.count){
    $mhead
    Write-Host # empty line
    $menu = @{}
    for ($i=1;$i -le $mlist.count;$i++) {
        if ($mlist.count -gt 1){
            Write-Host -fore Cyan "  $i." $($mlist[$i-1]) 
            $menu.Add($i,($mlist[$i-1]))
        }else{
            Write-Host -fore Cyan "  $i." $mlist
            $menu.Add($i,$mlist)
        }
    }
    Write-Host # empty line
    $global:ans = Read-Host 'Please enter selection'
}
$global:selection = $menu.Item([int]$ans)
```

Comment: What was the data contained in the array that was passed into the function? I have tried with both dynamic and static arrays of strings.

Comment: Ok, so update...my array has 12 items. I can select 1, 10, 11 and 12 but not 2-9. My array is built by querying vCenter and selecting hosts that match specific criteria. So my array contains the host names of 12 ESXi hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read-Host reads a string, and this line:

```
While ($ans -lt 1 -or $ans -gt $mlist.count){
```

Compares it against numbers. In that kind of comparison, PowerShell casts the thing on the right to the type of the thing on the left.  `$ans` is `"5"` and `$mlist.count` becomes `"12"` and string sorting puts them in order `"12","5"` so it triggers `$ans -gt $mlist.count` and loops again.

Fix: cast it to an integer.

```
$global:ans = Read-Host 'Please enter selection'
$global:ans = $global:ans -as [int]
```

It's a good practise to have fixed things on the left when testing equality/greater than/less than, and variables on the right, for this reason.

If I were commenting on the whole thing, I might rewrite it as:

```
$mlist = ('a')#,'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k')

# Force $mlist to always be an array, even if only 1 thing in it, to remove if/then test.
$mlist = @($mlist)


$global:selection = $null

Do
{
    $mhead
    Write-Host # empty line

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $mlist.count; $i++)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "  $($i+1)." $mlist[$i]
    }
    Write-Host # empty line
    $global:ans = (Read-Host 'Please enter selection') -as [int]

} While ((-not $ans) -or (0 -gt $ans) -or ($mlist.Count -lt $ans))

$global:selection = $mlist[$ans - 1]
$global:selection
```

This gets rid of the if/then, it gets rid of the `$menu` dictionary, it gets rid of initialising $ans first by using do/while.

Comment: Works perfectly. I was having issues when $mlist only contained a single item, so modifying this to address that issue helps as well. Thank you!

Comment: great answer with explained reasoning. Solved my problem I am having with building a menu dynamically from an array.

Comment: @Jonny_Bravo that's nice to hear, cheers :-)